# Nicer syntax for commands in sbt possible?

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

In sbt 0.7.7 and earlier you could add a new processor just like this:

```
*lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1
```

and would use it like this:

```
lift create project-blank
```

I **do** understand that in sbt 0.10 and later versions they are called commands now.

However, is there a way to shorten this command syntax?

```
lifty create lift snippet
```

to

```
lifty create snippet
```

or even

```
lift create snippet
```

This syntax would be more concise.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alias for the command.

e.g.

```
alias lift_create_snippit=lifty create lift snippet
```

or

```
alias lcs=lifty create lift snippet
```

Comment: That's sweet but in this case I have to create aliases for all possible Lifty command combinations or at least for the most common ones. It seems that there's no slick alternative for this, huh?